# Why am I getting Invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const vec&'

Tags: c++

## Introduction

I am using the [itpp](http://itpp.sourceforge.net/devel/misc__stat_8h.html) library version 4.3.1 in order to compute the skewness of a vector. The library can be downloaded from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itpp/files/itpp/4.3.1/).

The library can be install as follows:

```
mkdir build;
cd build;
cmake ..
make
sudo make install
```

---

## Source code

I am using the following source code to compute the skewness.

```
#include <itpp/stat/misc_stat.h>

using namespace itpp;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   vector<double> x{2,3,4,5,6};
   double skew = skewness (x);
   return 0;
}
```

---

## Skewness function in the library

```
double  itpp::skewness (const vec &x)
    Calculate the skewness excess of the input vector x.
```

---

## error

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const vec& {aka const itpp::Vec<double>&}’ from expression of type ‘std::vector<double>’
    double skew = skewness (x);
                             ^
In file included from  main.cpp:3:0:
/usr/local/include/itpp/stat/misc_stat.h:336:20: note: in passing argument 1 of ‘double itpp::skewness(const vec&)’
 ITPP_EXPORT double skewness(const vec &x);
```

---

I don't understand why am I getting this error.

Thank you.

Comment: what's the prototype for `skewness`?

Comment: double  itpp::skewness (const vec &x)

Comment: Did you try changing vector<double> x{2,3,4,5,6}; by Vec<double> x{2,3,4,5,6};?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`skewness()` appears to take a parameter of type `const itpp::Vec<double>&`, but you are giving it a `std::vector<double>`, which cannot implicitly be converted into the former type.  You need to declare `x` to be of type `itpp::Vec<double>` instead, or maybe you can explicitly convert `x` to an object of that type, provided itpp lets you do that (I don't know the library).

Answer (score 3):

A `const vec&` is not a `const std::vector&`, so the argument does not match.